# Make toolbar appear when approached by cursor

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, pyside, toolbar

I want to create a toolbar that does not appear until the cursor approaches the toolbar's position.

Something like, for example, vlc when fullscreen the toolbar below disappears after a while if inactive and when you approach it with the cursor, it appears.

Can I do that with PyQt or PySide, i.e. make a toolbar invisible until the cursor is in the upper part of my window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very interesting !

Yes, you can. Keyword is track mouse all time when move. In pyqt use `QWidget.mouseMoveEvent (self, QMouseEvent)`, But this method only track when mouse is press so your have to enable all move by using `QWidget.setMouseTracking (self, bool enable)` it.

OK, please see my example code implement in `QWidget` also your can implement `QMainWindow` (Different is `QMainWindow` already have `QMenuBar`), hope is help;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QTestWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(QTestWidget, self).__init__()
        self.myQMenuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        exitMenu = self.myQMenuBar.addMenu('File')
        exitAction = QtGui.QAction('Exit', self)        
        exitAction.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)
        exitMenu.addAction(exitAction)
        self.myQMenuBar.hide()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.myQMenuBar.setVisible(True if eventQMouseEvent.y() <= 23 else False)
        QtGui.QWidget.mouseMoveEvent(self, eventQMouseEvent)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myQTestWidget = QTestWidget()
myQTestWidget.show()
myQApplication.exec_()
```

---

**`QWidget.mouseMoveEvent (self, QMouseEvent)` Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent

**`QWidget.setMouseTracking (self, bool enable)` Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setMouseTracking

---

Regards,